# soap based web service in BB 10

Tags: web-services, soap, blackberry, wsdl, blackberry-10

I am just started development in BB10 .I need to call soap based web service from URL .I google it and found one weather example .But it not help me.Actually I want to to call a method Example like
getVersionReturn .
from url so that my concept clear .Then I will call my other methods
here is my url.

http://railapps.firstgroup.com/FirstGroupRailApps/services/RailAppsCAWS?wsdl

The return value is response like :1.3 .

can you help me to call one method on button click ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this isn't full solution, but it will show you the important part (this is cascades solution)

```
Button {
            text: "click"
            onClicked: {
                dataSource.load();
            }
        }
```

and

```
attachedObjects: [
        DataSource {
            id: dataSource
            source: "http://railapps.firstgroup.com/FirstGroupRailApps/services/RailAppsCAWS?wsdl"
            type: DataSourceType.Xml
            remote: true

            onDataLoaded: {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
            }
            onError: {
                console.log(errorMessage)
            }
        }
    ]
```

so all you need to do is to search through that data.